# How to use pipe operator in yml file

Tags: continuous-integration, pipe, yaml, buildkite

I am generating a `pipeline.yml` file and in the command step, I need to do something like `curl google.com | sh` but it seems to be interpreted literally.

I tried substituting the command step with shell but it doesn't seem to be supported. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Pipe characters can have special meaning in YAML. Have you tried wrapping the command in quotes to make sure it's a string?

```
steps:
- command: "curl google.com | sh"
```